# Handling error of json deserialisation

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

How to get original json string (that was passed to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method) from JsonSerializer.Error handler ?

```
public MyModel ParseFromJsonString(string jsonString)
{
     var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
     {
         jsonSerializerSettings.Error = OnError;
     }
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonString, jsonSerializerSettings);
}

...

private void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs)
{
     //How to get this from current place ?
     string originalJsonString; 
     //in log record I want to mention incoming json string that was processed by deserialization
     logger.Error("error: {0}, happened at deserialisation json: {1}", errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message, originalJsonString);
     //allows to continues deserializing, ignoring error and prevents throwing exception
     errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
 }
```

There are no such property in errorEventArgs, then I thought that it should be in "sender" which is instance of JsonSerializer, it contains many properties, but there I also did not found. 
Do not understand, why so cool package as json.net did not include this. String is a reference type, so it should be possible to store reference to the same string instance in errorEventArgs and no problems with consuming additional memory for duplicating (what can decrease performance in case of big json)

Answer (score 3):

By converting your error handler to lambda, you can access it with the help of c# compiler.

```
public MyModel ParseFromJsonString(string jsonString)
{
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Error = (sender, errorEventArgs) => 
        {
            //You can use your "jsonString" here
        }
    };

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonString, jsonSerializerSettings);
}
```

*PS: How does it work? [C# Closures Explained](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained) , [Closures In C#](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/closures-in-c/)*

Comment: Thanks, EZI! It is not quite what I expected, but nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked through the `ErrorEventArgs` and there is no property with the original string within the class. However you could do something similar to EZI's answer.

Change the method signature of your `OnError` method to something like this:

```
private void OnJsonError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs, string jsonString)
```

Then within your `JsonSerializerSettings` construction do the following:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
  Error = (sender, errorEventArgs) => { OnJsonError(sender,errorEventArgs,jsonString); }
};
```

That way you maintain the re-usability of the `OnJsonError` method while adding minimal lines of code to your original work.